# Create reference table or array inside of the code

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, reference

I am trying to create a function that allows me to put in a location number and the result will give me a unique location code.  The problem is I want all of the referencing done inside of the macro code, not to get the information from somewhere in the spreadsheet.  (this code is going into an add-in so there is no worksheet to reference from).  I basically want to do a vlookup but inside of the code, not in a worksheet.

I haven't been able to find out how to do this, the code below is something like what I am looking for, I am thinking maybe the use of an array but I can't figure out how to use it the way I want.

I know this doesn't work but I am trying to do something like this below so that when I type in `=GetCode(415)` the result is `001`

```
  Function GetCode(LocationNum As String) As String
  Dim Result As String

  'Built in reference table
  '
  '{   "415" : "001"
  '    "500" : "002"
  '    "605" : "003"
  '                   }

  Dim varData(2) As Variant
  varData("415") = "001"
  varData("500") = "002"
  varData("605") = "003"

  Result = varData(LocationNum)

  GetCode = Result

  End Function
```

Comment: Look at collections and/or dictionaries, they will suit your code more.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object

Comment: Don't see how that code can work with `LocationNum` as an argument and a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nathan_Sav has already mentioned, you can use a collection or dictionary instead, which are much more efficient.  Here's an example using the dictionary object.  Note that it uses early binding, so you'll need to set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library `(Visual Basic Editor >> Tools >> Reference)`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'set a reference (VBE >> Tools >> Reference) to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library

    'declare and create an instance of the dictionary object
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'set the comparison mode for the dictionary to a case-insensitive match
    dic.CompareMode = TextCompare

    'add keys and associated items to the dictionary
    dic.Add Key:="415", Item:="001"
    dic.Add Key:="500", Item:="002"
    dic.Add Key:="605", Item:="003"

    'print to the immediate window the item associated with the specified key
    Debug.Print dic("415")

    'clear from memory
    Set dic = Nothing

End Sub
```